# maven command line for running multiple profile

Tags: maven

i have 2 profiles in my pom.xml and need to package 2 WAR files simultaneously
this is pom

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>TEST</id>
        -- scripts
    </profile>
            
    <profile>
        <id>DEV</id>
        -- scripts
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

i tried

```
clean package -P Dev,Test
```

but alywas the generated WAR is the last one (Test) and Dev profile not run

Comment: Make two separate modules one for TESt and one for DEV where you locate the appropriate scripts...than you can work without profiles otherwise it's not possible to combine two profiles into a single run of maven-war-plugin ...The question is what kind of files are different for TEST vs. DEV?

Answer (score 1):

After  a lot of investigation i figure out it can't be done

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `P` arguments:

```
mvn clean package -P Dev -P Test
```

Comment: not working also , the only generated WAR is the Test

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that, you need to separate Maven runs.

Comment: how i can do this ?

Comment: Call `mvn clean package -PDev` and then call `mvn clean package -PTest`

Comment: i need to call them together

Comment: As I said: Not possible. At least not with the profiles in the way you have them. You could probably define a Test profile that does not build a main artifact, but attaches an artifact as side artifact to the main build process.